# Refresh Update Panel c#

Tags: c#, updatepanel, webforms

I have an update panel that seems to not being refreshed when I click the delete button. I know the row is getting deleted bc if i leave the page and come back then the row is no longer there. Any idea why the update panel is not getting refreshed though?

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">

  protected void btnDeleteMessages_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

  DeleteRow();

  UpdatePanel1.Update();

}
```

Comment: It could be helpful to see `DeleteRow`.

Comment: Please show more of your html and code behind.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using any sort of data-bound controls inside of the update panel, you'll need to call the `DataBind()` method on each of those controls to see updates to the underlying data reflected on your page.

I suspect that this could be the problem, especially if your `DeleteRow()` method makes changes to the underlying data, and not to the table itself.

Comment: @auwall12688 Are you using a data source control on your aspx page?  If yes, is it inside the UpdatePanel?  The other question is: are you using multiple UpdatePanels?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have CausesValidation property set to "True"? If yes, then try making it to false and see.  DeleteRow also could be of help.

If not, lets see if this code snippet does the job?

```
if (ButtonClick!= null)
        {
            Page.GetType().InvokeMember(ButtonClick.Method.Name, BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, Page, new []{sender, e});
        }
```